# How to make Google Test detect the number of threads on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, googletest

When running the death tests written using Google Test framework the following warning is produced for each of the tests:

```
[WARNING] .../gtest-death-test.cc:789:: Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe
particularly in a threaded context. For this test, Google Test couldn't detect
the number of threads.
```

Is there a way to make Google Test detect the number of threads on Linux?

Comment: One would think that the clever people of google would know how to do that if it was easy? ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Well, sometimes there are too many easy things to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've looked at the source code and it turned out that detection of the number of threads is implemented only for MacOS X and QNX, but not on Linux or other platforms. So I implemented missing functionality myself by counting the number of entries in `/proc/self/task`. Since it might be useful for others I'm posting it here (I've also sent it to the [Google Test group](https://groups.google.com/group/googletestframework)):

```
size_t GetThreadCount() {
  size_t thread_count = 0;
  if (DIR *dir = opendir("/proc/self/task")) {
    while (dirent *entry = readdir(dir)) {
      if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)
        ++thread_count;
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }
  return thread_count;
}
```

As of 25 August 2015, Google Test [implements `GetThreadCount` on Linux](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/1f87a0970dc0880c954ea4066fd7b72fad6fb089/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc#L104-L108):

```
size_t GetThreadCount() {
  const string filename =
      (Message() << "/proc/" << getpid() << "/stat").GetString();
  return ReadProcFileField<int>(filename, 19);
}
```

Comment: Slight optimisation, since all the entries would be numbers, you could just do `if (entry->d_name[0] != '.') ... ` instead of your two calls to strcmp... I'm sure it doesn't matter really...

Comment: I do like your solution, by the way.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Thanks. You are right about the performance, but it is only for death tests which are slowish anyway.

Comment: Here's a link to the gtest issue and patch (tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.9): 
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=464&q=couldn%27t%20detect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care much about the test execution time, a convenient alternative is to use:

```
::testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style = "threadsafe";
```

More details [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#death-tests-and-threads).

Comment: I do care about test execution time, but thanks for the answer. Didn't know about this option.

Comment: It can be also passed as command line argument: `--gtest_death_test_style=threadsafe`